# Pipe string into STDIN of command in Golang

Tags: go, subprocess, pipe, exec, piping

I want to replicate the following `subprocess.run` function call in Golang. What would be the correct way to do it?

```
subprocess.run(['kinit', username], input=password.encode())
```

So far, I've figured out how to use `exec.Command` to run external commands, but what's confusing me is passing strings as input to `STDIN` of that command. Python's `subprocess.run` has a handy `input` parameter that takes care of this, how can I achieve similar results in Golang?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "strings"

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("kinit", username)
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(password)
    err := cmd.Run()
}
```

The `Stdin` attribute of the `Command` object is the `STDIN` pipe, we can set it to a `strings.NewReader` object containing the input string to achieve the same effect as of the Python snipped mentioned in the question.